# python library like librosa for videos

Tags: library, python

I need a library like [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) in Python for videos.

Librosa is for analyzing audio, sampling , etc. – so we can change audio for some float numbers that show in any time of audio ... in fact make samples from audio.

We can do it on videos, in face framing and make float/integer numbers that show each pixel or something else.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find a library like this. Any recommendation please?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand what it should do (changing float numbers in audio? Make numbers that show each pixel? What should that be?) – and never heard of librosa. Maybe someone familiar with DSP can understand it (or point out what is missing).

Comment: it should change video into frames and then make numbers that show each pixel.